# Scrollview in scrollview need to prevent simultaneous scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

In a view controller I add a custom view that contains a scrollview. The master VC also contains a scrollView. The problem is that when the inner scrollview reaches the end the outer scrollview is getting scrolled also.

I need to prevent the outer scrollview from scrolling at all when the other view is visible. 
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this block of code, where you are showing the custom view

```
if (otherView.hidden==false)
   outerScrollView.scrollEnabled =false;
else
   outerScrollView.scrollEnabled =true;
```